# Why Orochimaru tries to steal other people's bodies instead of just reincarnating into his own offspring?

Tags: naruto

I do not get it.

This guy has discovered how to be immortal by reincarnating in other people's bodies.

Why he nor anyone near him and even other people just knowing it do not suggest him to reincarnate into his own toddlers?

It would be totally legit in a world in which children are already been forced to work, kill and do war.

It would not be that bad: reproduction would be then considered as cloning and it would become normal in a few generations.

If even in real life we legitimately "kill" fetuses to get stem cells, why would then be a problem to clone people into newborns?

With widespread immortality ninja wars would make no sense and everyone would live peacefully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply using bodies identical to his own would run counter to his obsession to learn every jutsu there is.

Consider two of his potential hosts that we saw in the series Kimmimaro and Sasuke.

Kimmimaro was the last of the Kaguya clan and the only person left with the ability to use bone techniques making him the only chance for Orochimaru to acquire them though Kimmimaro's terminal illness ultimately made him unsuitable.

Then we have Sasuke stemming from his desire to obtain Sharingan and their ability to copy jutsu on sight which would allow him to easily expand his repertoire.

Comment: yes, it is the best answer because Orochimaru goal is to learn all the jutsu in the world.

Answer (score 0):

I have read it [here](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/56558/why-orochimaru-tries-to-steal-other-peoples-bodies-instead-of-just-reincarnate) that the technique lasts 3 years. I guess this could be a sufficiently valid answer, unless there is other info I am missing (I am at the 140th chapter).